# What is the best way to create a web traffic log in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a newspaper and would like to register the hits for every news article. I was thinking of tbl_hits with fields ArticleId and sort field timestamp (plus Other attribute fileds for headers, browser type).

However usually i get multiple hits for the same article at theexact same time so I guess I wont be able to register them since I will get duplicate key error.

What primary key + sorting fields would you recommend? Thanks so much.

Comment: Why not use something like CloudWatch logs for your web traffic log? What are you hoping to achieve by using DynamoDB? Without more details, it’s going to be hard to give a good answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure, Im also using analytics and IIS logs as well for regular analysis. In this case we are trying to add some specific add-hoc functionality to our CMS which includes the UserId of the registered users hits. To tell the truth I am not aware whether CloudWatch allows me to register this kind of customized log.

Comment: You can log whatever you want in CloudWatch, and if you format your logs as Json objects it’s especially easy to query them.